# How to allow others to connect to my Django website?

Tags: python, django, server, web

Now that I have created a website, I wish the users can connect to my website **within a local network**. However my website now can only be accessible from the localhost (my pc), the others are not able to connect to my website when typing my ip address for example xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000 on their browser. I launch the service on my localhost using **# python manage.py runserver**. May I know if there is a way/command to allow the others to connect to my website?

**Note:** I have tried **# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000** as well, which allow all incoming, but it didn't work.

Comment: Option 1: Configure your firewall to allow incoming connection to port `8000`. Option 2: Run your site on port 80 by `# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: Running django python process as root (to do it on 80 port) is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the port and now its worked. Thank you anyway. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `settings.py` write

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` and run `python manage.py runserver` `0.0.0.0:8000`

Note: you can use any `port` instead of `8000`

Comment: Hi, yea I have managed to do it. It seems like the port was previously occupied by someone, I tried changing the port and it works, thank you for your answering!

Answer (score 0):

There are steps to resolve this problem are:

**1.** Use `http://<your ip address>` than https

**2.** Then in settings.py write

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

**3.** Finally ran the server with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```